# Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed for crontab area

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2.3.4 version, suddenly i got error of "Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed".

When i debug, i found it adds theme for path "crontab/Magento/blank" which is not exist.

I checked in database theme table and all entries are correct.

[image]

Why magento adds them with crontab area even it is not exist?